# Best way to build a multiple filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I want to build dynamics filters with rails for one of my model but i don't know the best way to do that.

My model is en Event witch has a **Continent**, a **Country** and a **Month**.

So i want to be able to find an event with several filters. For example, "Found all events in Europe for the Month of Febrary"

What is the best way to do that. I have to make a function **findByfilter** in my Event model?

Thank you for answer, example are welcome!

(I use rails 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're looking for is a little beyond just using `scope` to create filters:

i.e.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_continent, lambda {|continent| where(:continent => continent)}
  scope :by_country, lambda {|country| where(:country => country)}
  ...
end
```

and then doing `Event.by_continent('NA').by_country('Canada')`

If you're looking to build a more formal search model with a mechanism to `to_s` and describe your search, I'd probably start with something like [Railscast 111](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form).  He builds an advanced search model, which basically lets you set fields then filter down based on what's set.

From that, you could implement your own `to_s` method (or another name if you prefer) that would take a look at which search attributes have been set, and build a nice string to describe it.